# Migrating curl command to cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, curl, salesforce, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to login to salesforce.com API. Following [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm) tutorial I am able to do so, but when migrating my code to cakephp 3 I get the same access denied response.

The login credentials work, if I do:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token \
  -d 'grant_type=password&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&username={USERNAME}&password={PASSWORD}'
```

I get a valid session token, etc.

Here is the code I being using so far without luck:

```
//USING CURL 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=password&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&username={USERNAME}&password={PASSWORD}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

debug($status); //(int) 400

debug($result); //'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}'
```

//USING CAKEPHP HTTPCLIENT

```
$data = [
    "grant_type"        => "password",  
    "client_id"         => {CLIENT_ID},
    "client_secret"     => {CLIENT_SECRET},
    "username"          => {USERNAME},
    "password"          => {PASSWORD},
];

$http = new Client();
$response = $http->post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", $data);

debug($response->body()); //'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}'
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

**-- SOLVED --**

I actually solved this problem. It seems that Salesforce requires TLSv 1.1 (or) TLSv1.2 to reply the token. My MAMP curl php version was using TLSv 1.0 and my terminal curl version was using TLSv1.2. That was why it worked on the terminal and not on php.

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000099li) is the thread on another forum with the solution.

Comment: try specifying the user agent header for instance : `User-Agent: curl/7.43.0`

Comment: @BertrandMartel try it but with no luck. Thanks.